# Opensource на Javascript

Tags: javascript, opensource

Ребятки, подскажите какие-нибудь opensource проекты на Javascript. И расскажите имели ли вы сами опыт работы над opensource проектами.

Comment: Очень тронко...

Comment: в каком смысле ?

Comment: jquery? Помнится jquery получили даж какой-то приз в качестве сабжевого проекта...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что вспомнил:

- [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)
- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)

Comment: Не знал что фреймворки являются opensource проектами. Спасибо большое.

Comment: А какие JS проекты не opensource?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/languages/JavaScript - проекты, использующие JavaScript на Github. Абсолютное большинство - free software/open source.